# facebook social plugins - chrome browser on pc issue

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

I am implementing social plugins from facebook and it seems to work on all browsers **except chrome on PC**.
I used the [code from facebooks site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/)
Also i added this `<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">` and added `window.onload = function() {
        FB.xfbml.parse();
    }`

heres what i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=306********4607";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.onload = function() {
        FB.xfbml.parse();
    }
</script>

<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://example.com"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue. By disabling my extension [Disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disconnect/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo) all the social plugins now appear without errors